# Visa for France - showing actual hotel booking?

Tags: visas, france, schengen, paperwork, bookings

I am in UK planning to apply for Schengen visa via French Embassy. The application document requirements for the visa states that you are required to submit:

> Proof of Hotel reservation confirmation required from the actual
>   hotels throughout the whole itinerary showing the hotel's full contact
>   details, proof of payment and applicant's name

However I am planning to get the hotel booking done from [booking.com](http://booking.com) as it is convenient and has better offers. Will that be acceptable for visa submission? Is it ok to submit the confirmation from booking.com as long as it states my name and complete hotel details (name, location..)?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning your nationality or the passport you hold. If you are a UK citizen then you have the right to travel/live/work anywhere in the EU without a visa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be enough. Your confirmation from the on-line booking site would include all the required: it will note that the hotel confirmed the reservation, it will detail the required information about the hotel, and will also include a receipt showing proof of payment. It will also include your name on the reservation, and on the receipt.

The idea is to prevent people from coming in saying "I called the hotel and made the reservation". Showing a paid reservation from a known website would do the trick. Especially if the cancellation policy is restrictive (i.e.: no refunds, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. " will also include a receipt..", actually from a earlier reservation I know that they print all the hotel amount details etc. in the reservation confirmation but don't give anything separate as a receipt of payment.. is that ok

Comment: @Pradeep they don't give you a receipt at all??? AFAIK in Europe its illegal, they must give you some kind of receipt that should include the VAT paid.

Comment: For prepaid bookings, the confirmation is the receipt.  For bookings paid at the hotel, there has been no payment and thus no receipt either.

Comment: @jpatokal that kind of confirmation would probably not satisfy the embassy. The requirement is clearly to have a **prepaid** itinerary. I specifically mentioned that the reservation must be **paid** in my answer.

Comment: Hotel reservations at most major chains will require a valid credit card for confirmation, which is proof enough for the hotel of your ability to pay, and thus _presumably_ proof enough for the embassy.  But sure, if you want to play it safe, a prepaid booking will leave no margin for error -- and will screw you over if your visa is denied.

Comment: @jpatokal that's the whole point. Its not the ability to pay, its the travel plan that you give to the embassy. They want to make sure that what you tell them that you're going to do is exactly what you're going to do, and not say cancel the hotel reservation the minute you get the visa stamped and go to wash dishes as an illegal employee in a restaurant in Paris.

Comment: @littleadv, 90% of hotel bookings I checked don't take the booking money beforehand so they do not give a receipt or VAT. In the email confirmation they send, they mentioned the total amount and the current amount charged as zero. (to be paid when checking in). So I ended up booking directly from a hotel (which still uses the secure booking .com payment framework) and got a confirmation email from the hotel directly. I submitted that and got my visa. Thanks for the suggestion to ensure that all the hotel details are there in the printout. It helped.

Comment: @Pradeep I have different experience from the US, usually if you don't want to pay extra, you pay upfront and non-refundable. Especially on discount online sites (like hotwire, travelocity, and priceline which booking.com is affiliated with). But I'm glad it all worked out for you, they are after all reasonable and won't put unnecessary difficulties for honest tourists.

Answer (score 5):

An online booking confirmation (usually sent to your email after confirming your transaction with booking.com) is enough. I did this last year. Just be sure to send the details address + contact number of the hotel.